# Julia equivalent for rgl R package?

Tags: plot, julia, rgl

I would like to know whether there exists in Julia something which would be rougly equivalent to the `rgl` package in R language; i.e., a library allowing for a dynamic/interactive representation of 3D plots, 3D surfaces, etc.

A bit of context: if you're studying, for example, morphometrics, you regularly end up with files in [PLY format](https://github.com/JuliaGeometry/PlyIO.jl), or another format produced by 3D scanners. In R, you can for instance visualize (in an interactive way) easily a 3D surface acquired by such a scanner (here, a set of molars):

[image]

Do we have currently a similar feature in Julia? If so, which library should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: The Julia home page https://julialang.org/ currently shows some 3D graphs. I don't know how interactive they are, or whether there's PLY support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Makie.jl](https://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/), specifically via either the GLMakie.jl or WebGLMakie.jl backends, is a good option for interactive plots. For instance,  the following example from the [BeautifulMakie gallery](https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/surfWireContour/)

```
using GLMakie
let
    x = y =  LinRange(-2, 2, 51)
    z = (-x .* exp.(-x .^ 2 .- (y') .^ 2)) .* 4
    zmin, zmax = minimum(z), maximum(z)
    cmap = :viridis
    fig = Figure(resolution = (900,900))
    ax = Axis3(fig, aspect = :data, perspectiveness = 0.5, elevation = π/9,
        xzpanelcolor= (:black, 0.75), yzpanelcolor= (:black,0.75),
        zgridcolor = :grey, ygridcolor = :grey,xgridcolor = :grey)
    surface!(ax, x, y, z, colormap = cmap, colorrange = (zmin, zmax))
    xm, ym, zm = minimum(ax.finallimits[])
    contour!(ax, x, y, z, levels = 20, colormap = cmap, linewidth = 2,
        colorrange=(zmin, zmax), transformation = (:xy, zm))
    wireframe!(ax, x, y, z, overdraw = true, transparency = true,
        color = (:black, 0.1))
    fig[1,1] = ax
    fig
end
```

opens an interactive window that can be rotated at will with the cursor.

[image: Interacting with Makie plot window]

I am not familiar with the PLY format however, so cannot comment on that aspect of the question.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, it looks like `GLMakie` has other interesting (although non-interactive) functions for that purpose; see for instance https://makie.juliaplots.org/v0.15.1/examples/plotting_functions/mesh/